# Calculating how long app runs in background

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I'm building a VR experience using a GearVR and Samsung phone.

I've tried to figure out how long the app has been "in the background" when `OnApplicationPause` has been triggered, and subsequently `OnApplicationFocus`.

I know that the app doesn't process anything while in the background so doing a simple 'timer' wouldn't work, thus the following:

```
private float pausedAt;

void OnApplicationPause(bool pauseStatus)
{
    pausedAt = Time.realtimeSinceStartup;
}

void OnApplicationFocus(bool hasFocus)
{
    if (Time.realtimeSinceStartup > pausedAt + 60) { // 60 for 1 minute AFK
         ResetExperience();
    }
}
```

This doesn't seem to be working, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You could get the system time at on pause and resume and compare them. Not a solid solution but it will work for decent users.

Comment: @EmreE I did try this however couldn't get it to work properly (on Android, worked fine on PC) but I'll try again.

Comment: @Giuseppe De Francesco had to roll back your edit since this is about GearVR and Samsung phone. Also `OnApplicationPause` and `OnApplicationFocus` behave diffferely on Android devices.

Comment: @Programmer not sure what you mean by behaving differently? They have a guaranteed consistent behaviour across all supported platforms (as long as the platform supports running in background). Anyway is not a problem.

Comment: From doc *"On Android, when the on-screen keyboard is enabled, it causes a OnApplicationFocus( false ) event. Additionally, if you press "Home" at the moment the keyboard is enabled, the OnApplicationFocus() event is not called, but OnApplicationPause() is called instead"*. It will fail in the scenario described above.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your current code is that you are not also getting the  `pausedAt` value in the `OnApplicationFocus(false)`. You must do this as `OnApplicationPause` is called at certain times only. Also, do this with [`Time.time`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-time.html) instead of `Time.realtimeSinceStartup`.

Get the the time with [`Time.time`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-time.html) when the game pauses in the `OnApplicationPause` and  `OnApplicationFocus(false)` then get the time again when it resumes in `OnApplicationFocus(true)`. Subtract them to get the actual time your app waited in the background.

```
float pauseBeginTime;
float focusTime;

float totalTimeInBackground;

void OnApplicationFocus(bool hasFocus)
{
    //Detect return to game
    if (hasFocus)
    {
        Debug.Log("Focused");

        focusTime = Time.time;
        //Calculate how much waited in the background
        totalTimeInBackground = focusTime - pauseBeginTime;

        Debug.Log("Stayed in Background for " + totalTimeInBackground);
    }

    //Detect on-screen keyboard is enabled
    else
    {
        setExitTime();
    }
}


void OnApplicationPause(bool pause)
{
    //Detect Home button on Android
    if (pause)
    {
        setExitTime();
    }
}

void setExitTime()
{
    Debug.Log("Paused");
    pauseBeginTime = Time.time;
}
```

Comment: Actually, my code was fine and works, apparently `OnApplicationFocus` just wasn't being called at all when the app came back into view (no idea why not) so I added a condition to Update to call the function if the app is paused, as Update only starts working again when app comes back into focus.

Comment: It really doesn't matter if it works now or not, your code is still wrong since you are not checking the parameter in the `OnApplicationFocus` function. Like I said in my answer, you must do this or it will mess up your logic and timer. You need to understand how and when  `OnApplicationFocus` and `OnApplicationPause` are called. I don't think you do at this moment. That code will fail if you bring out the keyboard then press home button.

Comment: It's a VR experience, no one will have access to the device. It's meant to be a seamless experience that no one interacts with, just a video that plays when headset is on.

Comment: Oh ok that's fine.